# How to deploy dll's to Nexus repo

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, nexus, atlassian-sourcetree

Currently I am working on a .net project,I have 2 builds in Jenkins.Job 1 build artifacts(dll's) needs to be published to nexus repo and reference these dll’s from nexus in the Job 2.I am using Jenkins scripted pipeline.Please advise on how to make this work.

I have tried using stash and unstash but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755659/6309), you could:

- call a script doing the mvn deploy file for you
- parsing its output in a variable
- using that variable in your second pipeline

The last step [can use variables between stages of one pipeline](https://serverfault.com/a/884798/783).

Comment: Can we use maven deploy for .net apps.

Comment: @saisirisha1835 Yes, you can use mvn deploy to deploy any file to a regular Maven depot. Or to a Nuget depot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30858999/6309 or https://github.com/kaspersorensen/dotnet-maven-plugin

Comment: ,In this case I have to convert the dll into a nuget package and then publish them to nexus repo.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @saisirisha1835 You can either deploy it as a regular file, using the GAV (Group Aritifact Version) convention. Or you can convert it indeed, if your remote Maven depot is a Nuget one.

Comment: VonC, Could you please help me with a sample pipeline?

Comment: I used NuGet, created a .nuspec file and then run 'nuget pack' for individual csproj project,but in case if I want to nuget pack for sln(which consists of all csproj) how can I do it and publish to nexus and reference these dll's in Job2.

Comment: @saisirisha1835 I don't know enough about Nuget, but check if your Nexus does have a Nuget repository declared: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/.net-package-repositories-with-nuget

Comment: Yes, Ihave my nexus repo have both the nuget snapshot and releases repo declared.